# keeping http form values between redirects WITHOUT javascript or request params

Tags: html, forms, jsp, caching

Is there a way to make form values persist, using the browser cache only or something other than javascript when 302 redirecting back to a page after server validation fails in a servlet? Or also when an  link is clicked, is there a way to keep values populated?

I HAVE TRIED

```
request.sendRedirect("/index.jsp?error=1")
```

and it does not work, clearly.

i have also tried

```
<a href="">
```

to refresh a page while maintaining form values

along with

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="public">
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example, and update your question then. In short: do not write an essay explaining what you (want to) do, **show your code** instead (what have you tried so far).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not.

When a page loads, form controls can be populated only with default values (e.g. via `value` attributes) or JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Well the browser can definitely use cached values, like when you hit refresh, Are you saying the browser will never use those values unless the refresh button is manually hit? I was hoping it would have to do with duplicating the request, which i heard somewhere before.